# Manipulation of date in moment not working

Tags: momentjs

I'm trying to create a new Moment.js object from a specific date and manipulate the dates, but it's not letting me.

In a report, the user has a datepicker and 2 buttons for next week/previous week.
Whatever date is set, when the user clicks 'next week', the datepicker has to be updated and I need to get the start date and end date of that work week. Let's say my datepicker is currently set to Wed 6 Feb 2019. I'm trying to create a function to do 2 things:
- add 1 week to the datepicker ( Wed 13 Feb 2019 )
- get the 2 dates before and after the current work week. (AFTER SUN 10 Feb 2019 and BEFORE MON 18 Feb 2019)

The problem is I can't seem to generate a new date in moment from the datepicker string AND manipulate it.
If I create a new moment without passing in the date, so just moment() all the manipulations work fine.

As soon as I pass a date when creating the new moment(), the manipulations aren't stored. a and b just output as the same date.

What's strange is that I can't seem to store the manipulated date in a variable (a or b), however, my datepicker updates correctly.

```
var currentDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');   
var m = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'weeks');
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', m.format('DD-MM-YYYY') );
var a = m.startOf('isoWeek').subtract(1, 'days');
var b = m.endOf('isoWeek').add(1, 'days');
console.log(a.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
console.log(b.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

If datepicker is set to Feb 6 2019

Expected result:

```
Datepicker: Feb 13 2019
a //2019-02-10
b //2019-02-18
```

Actual result:

```
Datepicker: Feb 13 2019
a //2019-02-11
b //2019-02-11
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment not adding minutes to object created from javascript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046913/moment-not-adding-minutes-to-object-created-from-javascript-date)

Comment: Thanks @VincenzoC cloning the object worked!
    var a = m.clone().startOf('isoWeek').subtract(1, 'days');
    var b = m.clone()endOf('isoWeek').add(1, 'days');
I had already tried to redeclare m between a and b, but it wasn't working for me before.